Review Queues - Low Quality Posts always "Red notification" but always "empty" why?
I have recently gotten this privilege and being slightly obsessive I click on it often each time I see it turn red... but it is always blank.
Does anyone know what is going on or why this is happening?

This has happened to me and I don't know why either.  My theory is that there are enough people using the site and not enough posts of that type that someone could have cleared the queue before you got to it.
Not sure if you're into web server stuff, but each page on this site is stateless, so if you click a link like "show me the review queue" you're getting the review queue as it is now, not as it is when you saw the notification.
They would have to program in timestamps or something into the red dots, which would be confusing (and rather pointless) so it is what it is.

Yeah, but that implies that there are enough people to actually resolve the post. Before I got there. How many people reacting does that take?

@wyrsa just one when it's a mod doing it (which seems unlikely).  Yeah, it's very strange that this is always happening to you.

It might be that... I've already clicked on the new post, put a comment on it... and then click on the review queue. So it thinks I already reacted?

Actually... There were no reviews today according to the page. So it is just red for no reason.

@well - you've got [tag:bug] on this so maybe the community mods will notice eventually, it could be a legit bug.
